# bootstrap dropdown full width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used bootstrap dropdown menu but its output as

```
a        b           c         d         e
       |/\-------------------------------|
       |           Sub menu here         |
       |---------------------------------|

But i want it as following

a        b           c         d         e
|-------/\-------------------------------|
|           Sub menu here                |
|----------------------------------------|


a        b           c         d         e
|-------------------/\--------------------|
|    Sub menu here                        |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Can anybody know how to do this?

Comment: it works if i use margin-left:-200px but i know it is not a right way to do this

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://bootply.com/A6cKEOBDpV

Comment: yaa exactly same that i need..thank you so much..